# Sorting items in a list

Tags: javascript

I am creating a to do list as a first project. When the user inputs an activity, it adds it to the list along with the start/end time. I want my code to sort the items in the correct order using the start time but I can't figure out how to go about doing this! I am wandering if you can helpp

Here's the Javascript where an item is added to the list:

```
addListItem: function(obj, type) {
            var html, newHtml;

            if (type === 'health') {

                html = '<div class="item row" style="color: blue" id="health-%id%"><p class="item_description">%activity%</p><p class="item_start">%start%</p><p class="until">until</p><p class="item_end">%end%</p><button class="delete_btn" style="color: blue"><i class="ion-ios-close-outline"></i></button></div>';


            } else if (type === 'work') {

                html = '<div class="item row"  style="color: red" id="work-%id%"><p class="item_description">%activity%</p><p class="item_start">%start%</p><p class="until">until</p><p class="item_end">%end%</p><button class="delete_btn" style="color: red"><i class="ion-ios-close-outline"></i></button></div>';

            } else if (type === 'leisure') {

                html = '<div class="item row"  style="color: yellow" id="leisure-%id%"><p class="item_description">%activity%</p><p class="item_start">%start%</p><p class="until">until</p><p class="item_end">%end%</p><button class="delete_btn" style="color: yellow"><i class="ion-ios-close-outline"></i></button></div>';

            }


                newHtml = html.replace('%activity%', obj.activity);
                newHtml = newHtml.replace('%id%', obj.id);
                newHtml = newHtml.replace('%start%', obj.startTime);
                newHtml = newHtml.replace('%end%', obj.endTime);


            document.querySelector(DOMstrings.list).insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', newHtml);
```

I thought about maybe adding all the start times into an array and then using the sort() array method but then I don't really know where to go from here.

Comment: Please click edit, then `[<>]` snippet editor and create a [mcve]

Comment: Also please DRY - don't repeat yourself: `html = '<div class="item row" class="'+type+'" id="'+type+'-%id%"><p class="item_description">%activity%</p><p class="item_start">%start%</p><p class="until">until</p><p class="item_end">%end%</p><button class="delete_btn" style="color: blue"><i class="ion-ios-close-outline"></i></button></div>';`

Comment: And `html=html.replace('%activity%', obj.activity).replace('%id%', obj.id).replace('%start%', obj.startTime).replace('%end%', obj.endTime);`

Comment: Please show an example of obj and how you call addListItem.

Comment: Thank you for your response and sorry for the lack of mine!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the little information you posted, I had to assume a few things.

The code below will help you continue your task

```js
const DOMstrings = {
  "list": "#container"
};
const list = {
  "health": [{
      "activity": "Health Act1",
      "id": "id1",
      "startTime": "2019-09-10T14:48:00",
      "endTime": "2019-09-10T15:48:00"
    },
    {
      "activity": "Health Act2",
      "id": "id2",
      "startTime": "2019-09-10T12:48:00",
      "endTime": "2019-09-10T13:48:00"
    },
    {
      "activity": "Health Act3",
      "id": "id3",
      "startTime": "2019-09-10T16:48:00",
      "endTime": "2019-09-10T17:48:00"
    }
  ],
  "work": [{
      "activity": "Work Act1",
      "id": "id1",
      "startTime": "2019-09-10T14:48:00",
      "endTime": "2019-09-10T15:48:00"
    },
    {
      "activity": "Work Act2",
      "id": "id2",
      "startTime": "2019-09-10T11:48:00",
      "endTime": "2019-09-10T12:48:00"
    },
    {
      "activity": "Work Act3",
      "id": "id3",
      "startTime": "2019-09-10T16:48:00",
      "endTime": "2019-09-10T17:48:00"
    }
  ]
}
const whatever = {
  "addListItem": function(obj, type) {
    var html = '<div class="item row ' + type + '" id="' + type + '-%id%"><p class="item_description">%activity%</p><p class="item_start">%start%</p><p class="until">until</p><p class="item_end">%end%</p><button class="delete_btn" style="color: blue"><i class="ion-ios-close-outline"></i></button></div>'
      .replace('%activity%', obj.activity)
      .replace('%id%', obj.id)
      .replace('%start%', obj.startTime)
      .replace('%end%', obj.endTime)
    document.querySelector(DOMstrings.list).insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', html)
  }
}
Object.keys(list).forEach(type => {
  list[type].sort((a,b) => new Date(a.startTime)-new Date(b.startTime));
  list[type].forEach(activity => whatever.addListItem(activity,type)) 
})
```

```css
.health .item_description {
  color: blue
}

.work .item_description {
  color: red
}

.leasure .item_description {
  color: yellow
}
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```